# FontAwesome | How to make icons line up with each other vertically?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using font awesome to create icons on my site.

The issue is that, some icons are taller than the actual icon content of the icon, so they don't line up on the baseline because of that extra height.

I want the icons to all be bottom aligned, on the baseline. Just like how letters are bottom aligned. For this to work, the icons must be only as tall as the content.

It is the actual :before inside of the .fa div that is taller than it should be. Here is an imagine which demonstrates 3 different .fa icons. One of them is taller than it should be.

I highlighted it's content box with blue before clipping it from Chrome.

You will notice how the bottom of the icon has extra space from some reason. That is the actual :before highlighted.

[IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTfJA.png)

How can I get rid of this space, so that the icons sit nicely baselined?

Comment: Does it have to be aligned on the bottom?  I don't think you're going to be able to do that with that particular icon unless you do some heavy manipulation and manual offsetting to account for the empty space in the bounding-box under the icon.

Comment: @TylerSells These are buttons side by side. They don't look right not being aligned vertically next to each other.

Comment: What I meant was that you could easily align them to the top of a parent container instead of the bottom since your problem spacing is on the bottom of the icon. However, looking at your example, it appears that they are already aligned to the top.  I have an idea.  Let me do some testing and I'll get back with you

Answer (score 0):

Please see this codepen example: https://codepen.io/vtsells/pen/oeJKNz

Essentially what I have done is wrapped the problem icon in a parent container so that I can then control what the height is supposed to be.  Since I can control the height of the icon this way, I can control where the bounding-boxes are in terms of alignment.  The alignment is done via flex-box in this example. `display:flex; align-items:flex-end //flex-start to align to the top, center to align to the vertical center`

Html:

```
<div id="container">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
   background:#888;
   display:flex;
   align-items:flex-end;
   padding:10px;
}
#wrapper{
   background:#ccc;
   overflow:hidden;
   height:29px;
   width:30px;
}
i{
   background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I want the icons to be bottom aligned. So I changed the code to align-items:flex-end. However, this still presents the same issue.

Comment: Even if everything is bottom aligned, that last icon to the right will still have the extra space on the bottom, which would keep it from being aligned.

Comment: Can you post a shot of what's going on?  When i align it as you suggested, it aligns everything to the bottom

Comment: https://codepen.io/vtsells/pen/oeJKNz  Please view the updated codepen.  I have added further explanation that might shed some light on things